# $A$ is trivially closed if and only if $X\backslash A$ is trivially open

Tags: general-topology

A set $U$ of topological space $X$ is called Trivially open if $U=$Int$(\overline{U})$

and set $C$ of topological space $X$ is called Trivially closed if $C=\overline{IntC}$

Prove that $A$ is trivially closed if and only if $X\backslash A$ is trivially open.

I have been trying this for a while now and have been going nowhere. I would appreciate if someone can point me in right direction.

Comment: You might want to know that the usual terms are *regular open set* and *regular closed set*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for the terminology.

Comment: My pleasure; makes it a lot easier to find out more about them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
X \setminus \operatorname{int}(A) = \overline{X \setminus A}\\
X \setminus \overline A = \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)
$$